# Override jackson property for generic class

Tags: spring, jackson

Im trying to serialize simple wrapper like:

```
@Data
public class Wrapper <T>{
       Data t; 
    }
```

And I have only access to actual data class. My goal is to override value of json field 'data' to custom one. Is there any simple ways to do that?

ps:
my goal:

```
{ "customData" : "value"}
```

what I actually got after Wrapper's serialization:

```
{"data" : "value"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following annotation that jackson understands

```
@Data
public class Wrapper <T>{

       @JsonProperty("customData")
       Data t; 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I have no access to Wrapper.class. Lets say it's imported. Is any chance to override propertry name withought creating ObjectMapper?

Comment: Question is still actual.